# What the equalivant code as SQL Server RAND ( [ seed ] )?

Tags: c#

What the equivalent code in C# as SQL Server T-SQL RAND ( [ seed ] )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to create a new random number in C#

```
var x = new Random(Seed);
var z = x.Next();
```

**edit** Left off the part of actually getting the random #

Comment: This creates a random number *generator*.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Random r = new Random();
int val = r.Next();
```